# Generic sort works for integers but not for other types

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, generics

I'm trying to sort an array (performance is not an issue, so I use bubble sort for simplicity) of any type in C, to do this I pass the sort function the compare function it should use to compare the different types (compareInt, compareDouble, compareString and so on...).
My program works fine for int, but is behaving very weird when I use double/string/anything else...
W

What's wrong and how do I fix it?

My code:

```
int main(void)
{
    int  a[] = {2, 7, 6, 4, 1};
    double b[] = {12.5, 2.7, 3.0, 5.5, 5.9, 1.0};
    char c[] = {'c', 'a', 'b', 'd'};
    char * d[] = {"abc", "bca", "cba", "abcd"};
    char e[][4] = {"bca", "abc", "cba", "dca", "za"};
    printArray(a, sizeof(a[0]), sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]), printInt);
    printArray(b, sizeof(b[0]), sizeof(b)/sizeof(b[0]), printDouble);
    printArray(c, sizeof(c[0]), sizeof(c)/sizeof(c[0]), printChar);
    //printArray(d, sizeof(d[0]), sizeof(d)/sizeof(d[0]), printStringPointer);
    //printArray(e, sizeof(e[0]), sizeof(e)/sizeof(e[0]), printStringArray);
    printf("\n");
    sort(a, sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]), sizeof(a[0]), compareInt);
    sort(b, sizeof(b)/sizeof(b[0]), sizeof(b[0]), compareDouble);
    sort(c, sizeof(c)/sizeof(c[0]), sizeof(c[0]), compareChar);
    //sort(d, sizeof(d)/sizeof(d[0]), sizeof(d[0]), compareStringPointer);
    //sort(e, sizeof(e)/sizeof(e[0]), sizeof(e[0]), compareStringArray);
    printArray(a, sizeof(a[0]), sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]), printInt);
    printArray(b, sizeof(b[0]), sizeof(b)/sizeof(b[0]), printDouble);
    printArray(c, sizeof(c[0]), sizeof(c)/sizeof(c[0]), printChar);
    //printArray(d, sizeof(d[0]), sizeof(d)/sizeof(d[0]), printStringPointer);
    //printArray(e, sizeof(e[0]), sizeof(e)/sizeof(e[0]), printStringArray);
    printf("\n");
    getchar();
    return 0;
} // pay no attention to the printArray methods, as they are just for debugging purposes.

int compareInt(void * p1, void * p2)
{
    return *(int *)p1 - *(int *)p2;
}
int compareDouble(void * p1, void * p2)
{
    double d = *(double *)p1 - *(double *)p2;
    if(d > 0) return 1;
    if(d == 0) return 0;
    return -1;
}
int compareChar(void * p1, void * p2)
{
    return *(char *)p1 - *(char *)p2;
}
void sort(void * arr, int arrLength, int sizeOfElement, int (*compare)(void *, void *))
{
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < arrLength; i++) // arrlength -1?
        for(j = 0; j < arrLength - 1; j++)
        {
            //printf("%c, %c", *((char *)arr + j * sizeOfElement), *((char *)arr + (j + 1) * sizeOfElement));
            if(compare(((char *)arr + j * sizeOfElement), ((char *)arr + (j + 1) * sizeOfElement)) > 0) swap(((char *)arr + j * sizeOfElement), ((char *)arr + (j + 1) * sizeOfElement));
        }
}
void swap(void ** p1, void ** p2)
{
    void * p3 = *p1;
    *p1 = *p2;
    *p2 = p3;
}
```

(I also plan for this to work with strings, that's why arrays d and e exist, but I didn't write the compare functions for the strings yet.)

The input for the program (the arrays as printed by printArray):

```
2, 7, 6, 4, 1,
12.500000, 2.700000, 3.000000, 5.500000, 5.900000, 1.000000,
c, a, b, d,
```

The output of the program (the arrays after supposedly being sorted as printed by printArray):

```
1, 2, 4, 6, 7,
12.500000, 2.700000, 3.000000, 5.500000, 5.900000, 1.000000,
a, a, a, c,
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen. As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem. (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).)

Comment: Your code does not compile; try posting a Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example.

Comment: How do you expect `swap` to work if it doesn't know the size of the objects it is swapping? (Hint: assuming that the objects are the same size as a `void*` won't work for objects which are not the same size as a `void*`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `swap` function is wrong. It currently pretends there is a `void *` in the array, when in fact there is an `int` or a `double` or whatever.

Probably it appears to work for `int` because on your system `sizeof(int) == sizeof(void*)` , but doesn't work for the other types because they are different sizes.

To fix this, change `swap` to use `memcpy`, copying the right number of bytes. Of course this means it will have to take the item length as an argument. (You could either declare a temporary VLA to be the 'third wheel' in the swap, or use the XOR trick).

NB. The very long line starting `if(compare(((char *)arr + j *` is hard to read, I suggest declaring two pointers instead of repeating the calculations.

Comment: Thanks, I was not allowed to use memcpy, so I made my own (casting the pointers to chars, then looping through until I get to the sizeof parameter and then swapped each byte).

Answer (score 0):

As I can see because of the missing function prototypes your code invokes undefined behavior. In that case you may get either expected or unexpected output.
Either place the function definitions above `main` or add prototypes for them above `main` function.

```
int compareInt(void * p1, void * p2);
int compareDouble(void * p1, void * p2);
int compareChar(void * p1, void * p2);
void sort(void * arr, int arrLength, int sizeOfElement, int (*compare)(void *, void *));
void swap(void ** p1, void ** p2);
```

Comment: I didn't include the prototypes because it's obvious they're there and you can deduce them from the code.